# Assigning different dictionaries from a combobox

Tags: c#, dictionary, combobox, decision-tree

I have a linear decision tree in which the user can select different comboboxes which create different possible outcomes in the forms they receive. In this case there are two factors that come into play that I need to create one outcome. Depending on the number entered in textbox3 and the selection of combobox3 the user receives different forms in the directory stipulated in textbox1.

I am most definitely not a strong C# programmer, however, I feel the majority of this is fairly sound since the only item that doesn't work is the link between combobox3.Text and Textbox.3 dictionary.

```
 public Form(){

    InitializeComponent();
    button2.Click += mainPageRule;
    button2.Click += mainPageCheck1;
    button2.Click += mainPageCheck2;
    button2.Click += mainPageSwitch;
    button2.Click += mainPageActivator;
}  
    protected void mainPageRule(object sender, EventArgs e){
    this.timer1.Start();
    string destination = textBox1.Text;
    string source = textBox2.Text;
    if (textBox1.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You forgot to set a destination!");
    }
    else if (mapping.ContainsKey(source))
    {
        string directoryName = mapping[source];
        foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(directoryName))
        {
            File.Copy(f, Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(f)));
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Oh No! The output code is incorrect or something went wrong! Please Try Again! -Love Joe");
    }
    if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
    {
        this.timer1.Stop();
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
    }}
protected void mainPageSwitch(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (comboBox3.Text == "Hybrid")
    { 
        string payout = "hybridMain";
    }
    else if (comboBox3.Text == "Corporate")
    {
        string payout = "swagMain";
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You Forgot to set your platform");
    }}
protected void mainPageActivator(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string destination = textBox1.Text;
    string source = textBox3.Text;

    if (payout.ContainsKey(source))
    {
        string directoryName = payout[source];
        foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(directoryName));
        }}
        private Dictionary<string, string> hybridMain = new Dictionary<string, string>{
             //THIS SECTION CALLS TO 1KN3 NEW ADVISORS
             { "0000", @"\\Server\A.L.E.X.A DATABASE\1KN3\New Advisor\NC0"},
         };
private Dictionary<string, string> mapping = new Dictionary<string, string>{
             //THIS SECTION CALLS TO 1KN3 NEW ADVISORS
             { "0000", @"\\FSN-SERVER\Server\A.L.E.X.A DATABASE\1KN3\New Advisor\NC0"},
             { "0001", @"\\FSN-SERVER\Server\A.L.E.X.A DATABASE\1KN3\New Advisor\NCRA" },
             { "0002", @"\\FSN-SERVER\Server\A.L.E.X.A DATABASE\1KN3\New Advisor\NCUA" },
             { "0003", @"\\FSN-SERVER\Server\A.L.E.X.A DATABASE\1KN3\New Advisor\NCB" },
             { "0010", @"\\FSN-SERVER\Server\A.L.E.X.A DATABASE\1KN3\New Advisor\NH0" },
             { "0011", @"\\FSN-SERVER\Server\A.L.E.X.A DATABASE\1KN3\New Advisor\NHRA" },
             { "0012", @"\\FSN-SERVER\Server\A.L.E.X.A DATABASE\1KN3\New Advisor\NHUA" },
             { "0013", @"\\FSN-SERVER\Server\A.L.E.X.A DATABASE\1KN3\New Advisor\NHB" },
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having all of your events fire on one handler, you should probably break those up to have the events fired by the particular controls  most appropriate change event handler. i.e. `ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged` or whichever. As each control changes the next the effect is cascaded until completion.

Assigning multiple event methods to a handler in a particular order does NOT guarantee that they are executed in that order. You would be better off refactoring to be more specific on your execution order.

Another way would be to chain the method calls at the ends of each of the previous sequenced methods which would guarantee that all events fired in order if you only want it on the button click.

Addition:

What I mean is, if all of those methods need to be reliably executed in a particular order you should have something similar to the following:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    public TestForm()
    {
        btnSubmit.Click += new System.EventHandler(button_click);
    }
    public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do some code
        SecondMethod();
    }
    public void SecondMethod()
    {
        // Do some more code that has to wait until first method is done.
        ThirdMethod()
    }
    public void ThirdMethod()
    {
        // Do your final code.
    }
}
```

Comment: I will be inserting small time delays to keep the program in line. However, the decision tree has to be completed before moving any of the files to their destination directories so I house them all under one Event Handler.

Comment: See my edit. Instead of assigning a bunch of events to a single handler, just chain your methods as needed. That way you have better control of if you should stop code execution or perform other tasks in a specific order.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense actually. I will definitely migrate my code to work in a more controlled linear fashion like the example above, thank you.

Comment: Any suggestions on making the source directory dynamically selected from combobox3?

Comment: Depending on how fixed these values are, you could approach it several ways. One would be to add entries to your appSettings section of your App.config file and then access them using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` or you could create a `public System.IO.Path GetSourcePath(MySourceType type)` method with `MySourceType` being an enum. In the `GetSourcePath()` function you just use a switch and return a new System.IO.Path pointing to the location you desire. These two methods aren't mutually exclusive either. A hybrid approach would probably be best.

Comment: Then you could put an event on the `comboBox3.OnSelectedIndexChanged` event. In that code use the above method to change the source directory.

Comment: I think you are going a little to high level for my understanding haha could you show me an example?